# M Language (Excel 2016 Get and Transform) Add several columns with totals

Tags: excel

The data source has columns 1 to 25. I need to insert several Totals columns each adding the values of 5 columns 
(Total1 = Col1+Col6+Col11+Col16+Col21; Total2 = Col2+Col7+Col12+Col17+Col22; .........;Total5 = Col5+Col10+Col15+Col20+Col25)

Other than manually adding five lines of Table.AddColumn, one for each total, is there a way to use a single line command? the real case consists of 375 columns, not 25.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a range from A2:Y50 (25 columns), you can use the [MOD](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/MOD-function-9b6cd169-b6ee-406a-a97b-edf2a9dc24f3) function to check a value to see if it is divisible by a divisor with no remainder. By inserting the column into the `MOD` function we can check the column in divisible by 5 and can offset this to account for the different totals you require:

### Total1

`=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$Y$50)*(MOD(COLUMN($A$2:$Y$50)+4,5)=0))`

This adds 4 to the columns to make column 1 column 5, but still takes the values from column 1.

---

### Total2

`=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$Y$50)*(MOD(COLUMN($A$2:$Y$50)+3,5)=0))`

This adds 3 to the columns to make column 2 column 5, but still takes the values from column 2.

---

...

### Total5

`=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$Y$50)*(MOD(COLUMN($A$2:$Y$50),5)=0))`

This formula doesn't add anything to the columns as they are already divisible by 5 with no remainders.